# App targeting Android 12 and higher, explicit value for `android:exported but I have already added android:exported=true and still an error will come

Tags: flutter, android-manifest

### All are set properly But still i have a Error

The first time, I'm getting a two-time error,

```
/Users/MYSoft/project/separate/ecfile/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
/Users/MYSoft/project/separate/ecfile/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.            
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs                 
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 8s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                        11.2s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

and I add android:exported="true" in the activity tag. Now I'm getting the same error on the same file, but now I'm getting a single error.

```
/Users/MYSoft/project/separate/ecfile/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.            
> Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 8s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                        11.3s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

### Current Android Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.ecsoft.ecfile">

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <!--android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"-->
    <!--android:name=".MainActivity"-->
    <application
        tools:replace="icon, label"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:name= ".Application"
        android:label="Ecfile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ecfile_logo">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            tools:node="merge"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <!--<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge"
            tools:overrideLibrary="com.squareup.picasso.picasso">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

> This code was running in targetSdkVersion 31. and I also want to targetSdkVersion 31 because of the app publishing.

Answer (score 3):

Your manifest seems to be correct, but you can get the same error also if your app includes packages which contains old versions of `AndroidManifest.xml` (without explicit `android:exported`). Probably this is exactly your case.

The first solution (and probably the suggested one, unless you have specific reason to avoid an upgrade) is to upgrade all your packages and libraries to a newer version which contains an updated `AndroidManifest.xml`.

If a specific package couldn't be upgraded (maybe because it's not supported anymore) you can try another approach:

1. Set a lower `targetSdkVersion`. The main objective is to compile the app correctly.
2. When the app is compiled, you can find a "merged" `AndroidManifest.xml` (your manifest + all the packages' manifests) there:  `build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`
3. Look for the activity that doesn't contains `android:exported` and copy/paste it inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to **override** the original one. Obviously, in your manifest, add the missing `android:exported` attribute.
4. Compile again with the desired `targetSdkVersion`